# Which FieldCodec to use when writing a RepeatedField byte per byte into a MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, md5, protobuf-net, memorystream

The protobuf SDK for C# contains an example project [AddPerson.cs](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/3.15.x/csharp/src/AddressBook/AddPerson.cs)

It uses [addressbook.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/3.15.x/examples/addressbook.proto), which defines a repeated field:

```
repeated PhoneNumber phones = 4;
```

I am trying to add a function to the AddPerson.cs, which would create an MD5 string out of the repeated field:

```
private string RepeatedFieldToMD5String<T>(RepeatedField<T> repeatedField)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    repeatedField.WriteTo(new CodedOutputStream(memoryStream), new FieldCodec<T>());

    return string.Concat
        (
            MD5.Create().ComputeHash
            (
                memoryStream
            ).Select(x => x.ToString("x2"))
        );
}
```

The problem is that there is no such constructor for the `FieldCodec`, it wants to have some arguments.

My guess is that I have to tell it "please take a FieldCodec, which would be suitable to writing an object byte for byte into an array"... but how to say that in C# :-) ?

In the [FieldCodec.cs](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/3.15.x/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/FieldCodec.cs) I have seen a `FieldCodec.ForBytes()` method, but it wants to have some tag. What would be a suitable tag here?

The reason I am asking this question is that I am trying to take a `RepeatedField` in my real project, generate a MD5 string over all of it - and use it in the If-None-Match/ETag HTTP header.

Comment: "What would be a suitable tag here?" - The tag for the field. It's not really clear exactly what you're trying to do, but I suspect you should be able to do it without fiddling around with `FieldCodec<T>`. The field codecs are really designed for internal use and generated code. (They'd be entirely internal if the generated code didn't need to refer to them.)

Comment: Thank Jon, so I should not touch it? I am trying to take a `RepeatedField` in my real app, put it into byte array and then generate an MD5 string out of the array.

Comment: "Put it into a byte array" could mean any number of things though. It's also important to note that different proto binary encoders could handle the same proto differently - while there's a *suggested* ordering and representation, there are lots of *also valid* representations.

Comment: Note that `RepeatedField<T>` itself doesn't know which tag the field is represented by, so there's no such thing as "How a `RepeatedField<T>` would be serialized" without knowing that. I suspect if you write down really a really detailed set of requirements for every scenario, it will be easier to help - and you may well solve it yourself.

Comment: One simple option: clone the `Person` object, clear all properties other than `phones`, then serialize the message. But as I say, you could get different results with different platforms.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there are many ways possible, but the [Message](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/3.15.x/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/MessageExtensions.cs) has a method `ToByteArray` to generate a byte array. Unfortunately there is no such method for a `RepeatedField`. I'd like to use the same way as `Message`.

Comment: You can't, because the field doesn't know the tag, which is part of the serialized format. If you look at the generated code, you'll see it works out the tag (field number and some other bits) when it creates the codec: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/3.15.x/csharp/src/AddressBook/Addressbook.cs#L132

Comment: While you *could* just always use field 1 (and work out the rest of the tag) this all feels pretty fragile to me.